# Max number of souls Dark Souls 2 SotFS PS4

Tags: dark-souls-2

In Dark Souls 2 the enemies disappear after you beat them several times, I think it's 10 times and then the enemy disappears.

So, my question is, how many souls could be gained in the first playthrough of the game if you kill every enemy till it disappears, and you never lose your souls. Has anyone done this?

Comment: If you grind an area until you've killed off all enemies, you could also use a bonfire ascetic to reset the area to a harder difficulty without having to go into a new playthrough. The bonfire ascetic also can be farmed, so the limit in a single playthrough would be whatever the hard cap on souls is.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to gaming stackexchange. You should give some background to your question. This seems to be an impossible question to answer.

Comment: Joining the Covenant of Champions makes enemies respawn infintely while in the covenant so there's effectively no max.

Comment: I completely forgot about this!! Anyway, I'm not asking because I want more souls, or because  I don't know how to increase my soul level. My question was very specific. First playthrough, no bonfire ascetic (didn't clarify this), no losing souls (if you die yoe get them back) killing all enemies... how many souls?

Answer (score 7):

As mentioned in the comments, there are ways to ensure that you can get unlimited souls.

Assuming that you are talking exclusively about offline play (playing online would also allow for a major portion of souls - until you surpassed everyone in your soul memory range) there are many ways to increase your soul collection. Items such as the Silver Serpent Ring, and the Tseldora Armour Set, can increase the souls you receive, making it easier to farm souls.

However, through the use of Bonfire Ascetic farming (as user [Question Marks](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/87290/question-marks) already suggested), this allows for unlimited soul farming. Additionally, the [Stone Soldiers](http://darksouls2.wikidot.com/stone-soldier) in Drangleic Castle respawn indefinitely, as they are needed to open the Soul-devouring doors. Even without employing any other methods, this is still possible to gain the max amount of souls in one playthrough.

As for what the cap actually *is* for souls held, well, the best I could find was to do with [Soul Memory](http://darksouls2.wiki.fextralife.com/Soul+Memory). The top tier extends up to 999,999,999 souls; so either that is the point where they stop counting, or they just cap soul collection there, since even levelling up from level 837 to 838 only takes a couple million souls (1.5-2 million; somewhere in that range, I believe).

Comment: I completely forgot about this. Anyway, that's not my question. I'm not interested in earning more souls, I only wanted to know how many souls could be gained IF you kill every enemy of the game till it doesn't respawn, in the first playthrough. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @David.R.S that is my answer - there is no definable amount for this. Even if you kill every single enemy in the game (which you'd have to count individually), calculate the souls they give (items grant more souls, as well as dealing enough damage can award more souls too), there are still ways to farm souls indefinitely in the first play through. Entering NG+ also awards more souls again, per enemy. So that is what my answer is saying - there is no definable "cap".